# Why doesn't CMake find gtk (via pkg_config) but cmd does?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, gtk, pkg-config

I am trying to include gtk3 into my c++ project, but each time VS2019 tries to compile the project it fails on a CMake error:

```
1> [CMake] -- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
1> [CMake] --   No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
```

Therefore I checked with CMD if the module exists and returns

```
C:\>pkg-config --list-all | grep gtk
gtk+-3.0                  GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtk+-broadway-3.0         GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtk+-win32-3.0            GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
```

I thought because I have multiple installations of MinGW and Msys that maybe the wrong pkg-config gets executed, because of that I set the **PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE** to the same path as the cmd uses. I also thought that the **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** might be the cause but I checked the output of `message(STATUS $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH})` with the cmd command `echo %PKG_CONFIG_PATH%`
both prints

> /b/msys64/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/b/msys64/mingw64/share/pkgconfig

- My hypothesis would be that cmake can't interpret the linux-style Path?
- Is it possible to set the pkg-config-path ? I already tried: `set(PKG_CONFIG_PATH ...)` and `set($ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ...)` but unsuccessful

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(testing)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "B:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\pkg-config.exe")
message(STATUS $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH})

FIND_PACKAGE ( PkgConfig REQUIRED )
PKG_CHECK_MODULES( GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0 ) 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_subdirectory(src)
```

#### System

- OS: Win10
- pkg-config=0.29.2
- Visual Studio 2019 (Community)
- CMake version 3.20.2